# Rails db migration fails on missing mariadb plugin shared library http.so

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mariadb, debian, shared-libraries

I have a debian server and mariadb server on second one. If I run the migration, it fails on this.

```
       Mysql2::Error: Plugin http could not be loaded: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mariadb19/plugin/http.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
       /var/www/test/app/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/lib/mysql2/client.rb:90:in `connect'
       /var/www/test/app/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/lib/mysql2/client.rb:90:in `initialize'
       /var/www/test/app/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:24:in `new'
...
```

I cannot find this file and running out of ideas. Connection works perfectly with mysql client and every test works, but migrations does not.

Please any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In our case the issue was the `host` parameter which was starting with `http://`.